# Using .map with a nested two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby, dictionary, each

I have a nested array, like this:

```
aux = [["None", ""],["Average", "avg"],["Summation", "sum"],["Maximum", "max"],["Minimum", "min"],["Count", "count"],["Distinct Count", "distinctCount"],["Max Forever", "maxForever"],["Min Forever","minForever"],["Standard Deviation","stddev"]]
```

Now, what i want to do, is to append "1234" (it's an example) to the beginning of the second element of each array, but not on the original array, like this:

```
new_aux = aux.map {|k| [k[0],k[1].prepend("1234")]}
```

Problem is that with this, the original array is being changed. I was reading about this and the problem seems to be the manipulation of the string, because if i convert that element to symbol, for example, the original array its not changed, like i want, but i don't exactly get what is the problem here and how should i do this.

By doing this, in new_aux i get:

```
[["None", "1234"],
 ["Average", "1234avg"],
 ["Summation", "1234sum"],
 ["Maximum", "1234max"],
 ["Minimum", "1234min"],
 ["Count", "1234count"],
 ["Distinct Count", "1234distinctCount"],
 ["Max Forever", "1234maxForever"],
 ["Min Forever", "1234minForever"],
 ["Standard Deviation", "1234stddev"]]
```

Which is what i want, the thing is that i have the exact same thing in the original array, which is what i don't want.

Comment: Note that you can use [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) inside blocks if the array is the sole block argument. `aux.map {|k| [k[0],k[1].prepend("1234")]}` could be written as `aux.map {|k,v| [k,v.prepend("1234")]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[prepend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-prepend) mutates a string itself, so using this method you change the source array. Use strings interpolation to achieve your goal `new_aux = aux.map {|k| [k[0],"1234#{k[1]}"]}`